# Map a Java Web Application to a subdomain

Tags: java, subdomain, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

How do I map my java web application, which I can access by typing :

```
(ip_address):8080/(program_name)
```

to a subdomain I just created

```
(program_name).(website).com
```

I am using glassfish. I tried searching for it on the internet but the instructions are for tomcat which I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept is called `Virtual Server` in Glassfish AS. See this link for an example on how to set it up:

http://pe-kay.blogspot.de/2013/05/configuring-virtual-servers-in-glassfish.html

Comment: do I need to create a subdomain on my domain or the glassfish will automatically create it for me?

Comment: You mean if you have to create a DNS-Record to point your subdomain to the IP adress of your glassfish server? Yes.